# No connection left in pool for cluster slots of Redis cluster when using PRedis library in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, redis, lumen, predis

My team have one project using Lumen(which is a micro framework based on Laravel). We use Predis to connect our Redis cluster and run some queue job on it. But sometimes(we can't re-produce) system will throw "No connections left in the pool for `CLUSTER SLOTS` in .." exception

```
[2017-08-17 14:05:35] bookmark.ALERT: Predis\ClientException: No connections 
left in the pool for `CLUSTER SLOTS` in 
....../vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Aggregate/RedisCluster.php:232 
Stack trace: 
#0 ....../vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Aggregate/RedisCluster.php(260): 
Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster->queryClusterNodeForSlotsMap(NULL) 
#1 ....../vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/Aggregate/RedisCluster.php(560): 
Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster->askSlotsMap() 
...
```

We have investigated for a long time. We think the problem might be in the Predis library of Laravel, and the way it maintain connection pool. It might because Redis cluster close connection in some reason but Predis library didn't reopen the connection when it try to make connection.

and here's our cluster setting structure:

```
'redis' => [
'client' => 'predis',

'clusters' => [
    // Setting for Queue
    'default' => [
        'options' => [ 'cluster' => 'redis' ],
        [
            'host' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'port' => 'xxx',
            'timeout' => 0.15,
            'read_write_timeout' => 0.15
        ],
        [
            'host' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'port' => 'xxx',
            'timeout' => 0.15,
            'read_write_timeout' => 0.15
        ],
        ...
    ]
]
]
```

Any one have idea on it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Same as what @7284 mentioned, in my case also the password was invalid. And the error was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Because you only see these exceptions intermittently, the timeout values in your `'redis'` configuration may be too low. I can only guess that bursts of traffic on the network between the PHP and Redis servers slows down communication enough to cause client connections to time out (after `0.15` seconds, as configured).

The Predis client throws ***No connections left in the pool for `CLUSTER SLOTS`*** when it fails to fetch the slots map from *all* of the configured Redis hosts (because, presumably, they all timed-out). You can reproduce this behavior by setting a really small timeout value like `0.0001`.

Try increasing the timeout values and consider monitoring the network for issues that cause latency.